# .NET MVC data binding methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I realize this doesn't necessarily apply to MVC exclusively, but bear with me.

Working with entity framework and models, I've read several articles on "best practices" where some people claim using repositories and unit of work is better, others claim it's overkill and using your models directly within your controllers with linq is better, so on and so forth...

Then we have view-models and lazy loading methods, but then with linq we can use joins to add multiple "models" to our data retrieval to fetch whatever we need directly in our controller or helper class.

I realize a lot of this ties back to the "separation of concerns" that is MVC and we can create multiple layers to map our data back whichever way we want, which is great, but let's say for argument sake my app run exclusively on MS SQL, with no chance of ever transitioning to another database type, will adding all the additional layers of separation to map data back give me any real benefit? I'm just trying to understand at which point does one conclude it's better to do it this way over that way?  I know some of this might consist of personal preference, but I'm looking for REAL LIFE scenarios where it's easy for me to conclude one way it better than the other AND what questions I should ask myself when deciding how many mapping layers do I need to get my data from my database to my view?

Answer (score 1):

One of the real benefits is when your models or your UI need to change independently of each other. If your view is only tied to a ViewModel instead of your entity, then you can make all of the mapping changes in one place (your controller) instead of needing to go through every view that your entity is being used and making changes there. Also, with ViewModels, you have the benefit of combining multiple data sources into a single object. Basically, you get a lot more flexibility in how to implement your UI if you don't tie it directly to database tables.